# Bottom line trimmed off printing string

Tags: go, printing, slice

I have a program that prints a multiline string, and it cuts off the bottom.Output:

```
[   ]
[██████╗  ██╗  ██╗ ██████╗  ██████╗ ]
[╚════██╗ ██║  ██║ ╚════██╗ ╚════██╗]
[ █████╔╝ ███████║  █████╔╝  █████╔╝]
[██╔═══╝  ╚════██║ ██╔═══╝   ╚═══██╗]
```

The Program used to generate it:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "strconv"
        "strings"
)

const one = `
 ██╗
███║
╚██║
 ██║
 ██║
 ╚═╝
`
const two = `
██████╗ 
╚════██╗
 █████╔╝
██╔═══╝ 
███████╗
╚══════╝    
`
const three = `
██████╗ 
╚════██╗
 █████╔╝
 ╚═══██╗
██████╔╝
╚═════╝ 
`
const four = `
██╗  ██╗
██║  ██║
███████║
╚════██║
     ██║
     ╚═╝
`
const five = `
███████╗
██╔════╝
███████╗
╚════██║
███████║
╚══════╝
`
const six = `
 ██████╗ 
██╔════╝ 
███████╗ 
██╔═══██╗
╚██████╔╝
 ╚═════╝ 
`
const seven = `
███████╗
╚════██║
    ██╔╝
   ██╔╝ 
   ██║  
   ╚═╝ 
`
const eight = `
 █████╗ 
██╔══██╗
╚█████╔╝
██╔══██╗
╚█████╔╝
 ╚════╝ 
`
const nine = `
 █████╗ 
██╔══██╗
╚██████║
 ╚═══██║
 █████╔╝
 ╚════╝ 
`
const zero = `
 ██████╗ 
██╔═████╗
██║██╔██║
████╔╝██║
╚██████╔╝
 ╚═════╝ 
`

var numbers = []string{zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine}

func getAscii(number int) [][]string {
        listOfNumbers := strings.Split(strconv.Itoa(number), "")
        var ascii [][]string
        for _, num := range listOfNumbers {
                intnum, _ := strconv.Atoi(num)
                ascii = append(ascii, strings.Split(numbers[intnum], "\n"))
        }
        return ascii
}
func LongestSlice(slices [][]string) int {
        var longest int = 0
        for _, slice := range slices {
                if len(slice) > longest {
                        longest = len(slice)
                }
        }
        return longest
}

func joinStrings(stuff [][]string) [][]string {
        var joined [][]string
        for lineNumber := 0; lineNumber <= LongestSlice(joined); lineNumber++ {
                var Oneline []string
                for _, item := range stuff {
                        //err := item[lineNumber]
                        //if err != nil {
                        //      panic(err)
                        //}
                        Oneline = append(Oneline, item[lineNumber])

                }
                joined = append(joined, Oneline)
        }
        return joined
}
func main() {
        stuff := joinStrings(getAscii(2423))
        for _, line := range stuff {
                fmt.Println(line)
        }
}
```

Why is this? I'm so confused on where to look.
 How can I fix this so it doesn't cut off the bottom? Sorry I included the entire program, I have no idea where the problem is.

Comment: Is there a need for all this dynamic build up of the collection? Given your stated goal, to print those characters, your code is very complicated. You could just have them all instantiated as part of a collection rather than as individual consts and then print each item in that collection rather than doing all this `joinString` stuff. Really none of that is necessary to achieve the functionality you're talking about.

Comment: Also, just one quick observation, after all the `joinStrings` stuff is done running you only have 5 items in the `stuff` array which is why you're missing output.

Comment: 1) if I just printed it, each ascii character would be below each other

Comment: 2) You are right about the collection thing, If you want to suggest a better version go on ahead

Comment: How do I fix the `[][]string stuff`slice only being 5 items long?

Comment: Some of this code is thought of from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220839/print-multi-line-strings-on-same-line

Comment: Not sure yet, but I'll play around with the code a bit as time allows and maybe fix that up. I'm pretty sure it's a bug in `joinStrings` but it's not obvious where the error occurs to me yet.

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just overingeneering in loop condition. Try

```
for lineNumber := 0; lineNumber <= LongestSlice(stuff)-1; lineNumber++ {
```

in outer loop in func joinStrings. See it works https://play.golang.org/p/eR4JJtY4T1

Comment: Yup, wrong argument to LongestSlice, also, rather than subtracting and doing an `<=`, simplify it and do `for lineNumber := 0; lineNumber < LongestSlice(stuff); lineNumber++ {`

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems overly complicated for what you're trying to accomplish. One simple way to do it is to take evanmcdonnal's advice and use a map to define how integers convert into their corresponding string constants, which looks something like this:

```
var integerToStr = map[int]string{
  0: zero,
  1: one,
  2: two,
  3: three,
  4: four,
  5: five,
  6: six,
  7: seven,
  8: eight,
  9: nine,
}
```

...in which case you can convert an integer like this:

```
if str, present := integerToStr[i]; present {
  // do something with the string
} else {
  // default to something else?
}
```

If you don't like variables in the package scope, you could also use a switch statement to do the same thing inside of a function:

```
var glyph string
switch num {
    case "1":
        glyph = one
    case "2":
        glyph = two
    case "3":
        glyph = three
    case "4":
        glyph = four
    case "5":
        glyph = five
    case "6":
        glyph = six
    case "7":
        glyph = seven
    case "8":
        glyph = eight
    case "9":
        glyph = nine
    case "0":
        fallthrough
    default:
        glyph = zero
    }
```

I also recommend coming up with a standard height for your letters and making that a constant along with the strings themselves. This allows you to join them horizontally rather easily by creating a fixed-length array, appending to each member of that array with the corresponding line of each string, then turning that into a slice and using "strings.Join" to do the work of joining the final string:

```
var out [glyphHeight]string

for _, glyph := range glyphs {
    for i, line := range strings.Split(glyph, "\n") {
        out[i] += " " + line
    }
}

return strings.Join(out[:numGlyphLines], "\n")
```

Another slightly pedantic thing I think bears mentioning is that you're incorrectly referring to your strings as ASCII. Go actually uses UTF for its strings. It doesn't really matter in this example, but you should keep that in mind.